# How to create a two column mobile responsive menu, when I have a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already have a Bootstrap responsive navbar, but now I need for the mobile version to look just like the one on the [Univisión Mobile website](http://www.univision.com/noticias) in which there are two columns, the first one with the different categories, and the second one with that category's subcategories. I want to make sure that when the user taps on "TV" they see TV's subcategories and so on, all without leaving the nav.

[image]

Is there an easy way of doing this, if I already have a bootstrap navbar? Or would I be better off designing a whole mobile version of the menu?
My desktop code is on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skmdcm58/):

```
<header id="header2">
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <h1><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logohead" alt="logo"></h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar-celeste-text">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">TV
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Shows</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">News Shows</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sports</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">News
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul role="menu" class="sub-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">World News</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Local News</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Other News</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sports News</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Columns</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Specials</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">App</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Other Category</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="search hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <form action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="get" role="form">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      <div class="field-toggle">
       <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search"/>
         <span class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-ca"   type="button" value="submit">Search</button>
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </header>
```

I'm also using [Smartmenus](http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/) for the 3 level menus.

Comment: Your markup doesn't look complete. Can you provide the complete `<header>` and any custom styles you may already have, maybe in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Thank you @ChrisYongchu, I did.

Comment: Since you're using Smarmenus, it looks like this can be done with their built in classes. http://www.smartmenus.org/docs/#main-menu-classes